# Diagonalization problem without knowing original matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let A be a matrix with eigenvalue $r=2$ with associated eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
          0 \\
         \end{bmatrix}$ and eigenvalue $r=1$ with associated eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
           1 \\
         \end{bmatrix}$. If $w=\begin{bmatrix}
           2 \\
          3 \\
         \end{bmatrix}$, calculate $A^{10}w.$

This is incorrect, but how I proceeded:

$$A^{10}w=\left(2\begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
          0 \\
         \end{bmatrix},1\begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
          1 \\
         \end{bmatrix}\right)^{10}\begin{bmatrix}
           2 \\
          3 \\
         \end{bmatrix}$$
$$=\left(2^{10}\begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
          0 \\
         \end{bmatrix},1^{10}\begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
          1 \\
         \end{bmatrix} \right)\begin{bmatrix}
           2 \\
          3 \\
         \end{bmatrix}$$ $$=\left(\begin{bmatrix}
           1024 \\
          0 \\
         \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
          1 \\
         \end{bmatrix}\right)\begin{bmatrix}
           2 \\
          3 \\
         \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
           1024&0 \\
          0&1 \\
         \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
           2 \\
          3 \\
         \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
           2048 \\
          3 \\
         \end{bmatrix}$$

Can someone correct this proof and possibly explain the correct "diagonalization" process here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix is $A=PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ has diagonal elements the eigenvalues, and the matrix $P$ has the eigenvectors in the same order. So we have

$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
2&0\\
0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\implies A^{10} =
\begin{bmatrix}
2^{10}&0\\
0&1^{20}
\end{bmatrix}
$$